# ipad pop over with text field to enter

Tags: ios, ipad, styles, uitextfield, popover

i have designed a pop over (tableview style) for ipad. Now like in asp.net i want a  option at the end, so that if user clicks it he can enter value into it. Can it be done?If so how? I have played with tableviewcellstyles and got a text box as well but for all options. If anybody has done, can you give me some ideas. Thanks.

EDIT : I should have mentioned i am using Monodevelop to develop this app.

Answer (score 0):

One approach, assuming you're using a Storyboard to create view and set properties:

In your UITableView object properties set "content" property to "Dynamic Prototypes".

Then add an additional Table View Cell to your table from the storyboard editor's UI object list (just like adding another label or button or whatever).

You should now have two TableViewCell objects in your table view. If not, add another.

Give both table view cell objects different identifiers (that is, set property "identifier" for each to different strings).

Set up the first cell to display your normal content.

Set up the second cell to display your unique "last row" layout.

In your code, in cellForRowAtIndexPath return the "main" cell for most rows, but the alternate cell for the last row:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // rows are 0-indexed
    if (indexPath.row == myDataSource.count) {

        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AlternateCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // populate contents...
    }
    else {

        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NormalRow";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // populate contents...
    }
}
```

For that to work, you'll have to tell the TableView that there's one more row than you have actual data for:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myDataSource.count +1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that i am using Monodevelop as the IDE. Have you worked with it before?